# Creating a human-like voice from instruments

Tags: robots

I was wondering if there is a way to create a human-like voice from, say, a set of guitar or piano strings. I suppose it would be necessary to build a sort of model to mimic the oral and nasal cavities, along with a mouth in order to achieve best pronunciation.

The purpose that I ask is for use in a robot. Instead of having to tediously record every sound, word, or letter, it could generate its own sound, with even a personalized voice, but not only that, it could make sentences flow with ease by using the correct tone of voice when asking a question, or when giving answers.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This has already been done to some extend. Have a look here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=muCPjK4nGY4

Comment: Now that's what I'm talking about! Now if only we could scale it to a much smaller scale.

Comment: What's wrong with a speech synthesizer and speaker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say, the structure of the mouth and nose is essential to humanoid sound.  You would have to simulate it effectively.  You also typically need at least one source of a tonal noise, like a string, and one source of white noise, similar to snare drum, to capture the full sound of the human voice.

This has actually been done, digitally.  The vocaloids are a set of virtual singers developed in Japan.  They're not perfectly human, but you can [hear how close we can get](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwRo8fQtqpE).  Not only are the character voices different from each other, but they actually can be tweaked for more individuality.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a digital representation is better because there is no need for a huge model. Either way, thanks for the response.